# XML elements with no value and schema checks

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

#### Background information that might not be needed but is included for completeness

I'm working on a system where all user input will be stored in an xml file. Currently user input is handled by an aspx.net web form. In the C# code behind I'm storing these values in an object then serialising back to XML The values are also serialised back from the XML into an object before being displayed for the user to edit.

#### Question

The data are represented in XML using the following schema (I appologise for the .Net specific prefixes)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <xsd:schema id="UserInput-Schema"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="urn:UserInput-Schema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

     <xsd:element name="userInputData">
       <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>

          <xsd:element name="someTextData" type="xsd:string"
            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />

          <xsd:element name="someOtherTextData" type="xsd:string"
            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />

          <xsd:element name="yetMoreTextData" type="xsd:string"
            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />


        </xsd:sequence>
       </xsd:complexType>
     </xsd:element>

  </xsd:schema>
```

However, I've been told that the user should be able to enter blank values, or not enter values at all. This wouldn't really be an issue, except that when input is left out of a field, the respective XML elements have no value after serialisation occurs. I'm using the .net XML serialisation method to convert my object to XML, this method seems to perform trimming (and XML keyword checks) on values before writing them out.

For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <userInputData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

         <someTextData>I love XML!</someTextData>
         <someOtherTextData/>
         <yetMoreTextData>More text</yetMoreTextData>

  </userInputData>
```

However, this XML will fail a schema validation check when reading back in because of the  element missing a value. Obviously, if I change the minOccurs value to 0 for the elements that can be missing values (according to newly presented requirements, that's everything), then the above XML example will pass the schema validation.

However, I don't like the idea of this because, in extremely rare instances, the user *COULD* access the XML files outside of the application and edit them. If a user was to completely remove an element (regardless of whether it has a valid value or not), then the XML will still pass the schema validation, but would be invalid for our purposes.

I was thinking of writing out internally recognised values for elements that are missing input (something like "Input not supplied") and reading the values as blank strings if found. For example, this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <userInputData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

         <someTextData>I love XML!</someTextData>
         <someOtherTextData>Input not supplied<someOtherTextData>
         <yetMoreTextData>More text</yetMoreTextData>

  </userInputData>
```

However, this has been vetoed because the XML values need to be human readable (ish) were the application be removed from the equation. Also, adds needless complexity to the reader and outputted files. I looked into the nillable tag (on a prompt from a colleague), but my research tells me that's not what nillable is for. Nillable (if I am correct) is used to inform the XML parser than the value is allowed to be NULL, not that we can assigned it no value.

Is there a more elegant way of dealing with this particular situation than setting the minOccurs values to 0, or writing out known blank values?

#### tl;dr

Is it possible to write out elements with no value in the following format:

```
<someTextValue />
```

And have it still pass a schema validation without setting the value of minOccurs to 0, or passing it a known (as in "this element is blank") value?

EDIT:

#### The .NET Technique I'm using to validate against the schema

Algorithm:

- Read the schema into an schema object
- Set up an XML Reader Settings object (with the schema)
- Read through the schema (we're not parsing at this point)
- If there are any errors, they are caught automatically by the ValidationEventHandler

Here is the code block I use:

```
private static void ValidateAgainstSchema(Stream schemaToUse, XmlReader documentToValidate)
{
  XmlSchema schema;
  // Ensure that the stream to the schema is read from the very
  // begining of the file.
  schemaToUse.Position = 0;

  // Read the schema from the stream into the XmlSchema object
  using (XmlReader schemaReader = XmlReader.Create(schemaToUse))
  {
    schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaReader, ValidationEventHandler);
  }

  // Add the schema to a set of schemas
  XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
  schemas.Add(schema);

  // Set up the schema reader settings
  XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
  settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
  settings.Schemas = schemas;
  settings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
  settings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationEventHandler;

  // Run through the xml file to be checked, before passing control back
  // to the calling method
  using (var validationReader = XmlReader.Create(documentToValidate, settings))
  {
    while (validationReader.Read())
    {
      // If we fail to read the xml file (badly formed, doesn't match
      // the schema, etc.) then we'll fall through to the event handler
      // (readerSettings_ValidationEventHandler) automatically.
    }
  }
}

private static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
  {
    /* warning while parsing XML file */
    // warnings can be ignored for now. These are not critical
  }
  else if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
  {
    /* Error while parsing XML file */
    // Errors are problems with the xml file (when checked against
    // the schema). These are critical issues with the conents of
    // the XML file.
    // Possibly throw an exception?

    throw new Exception(e.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Running ``xmllint`` against your XML file with ``<someOtherTextData/>`` and using your XSD, I do not get an error.

Comment: Hmm... That's quite strange. I've added a description of the validation methods (with code blocks, too). I doubt it's the .net Validation code I'm calling, so I wonder whether I'm doing it all wrong

Comment: I've never used .Net so I can't help much with the .Net code. I double checked [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation) in case ``xmllint`` had a bug. Your document validates there too. Maybe you are not using the schema you think you are using, or not using the input you think you are using. (I've certainly got my wires crossed once in a while during testing. Changed something for a temporary check, forgot to undo it, etc.)

Comment: @Louis I appreciate your comment, but I've stripped back the possible other XML schemata and can confirm that I'm only using the schema I need to, and I'm validating against the correct input file, too).